# FileUtils writelines "not applicable for arguements"?

Tags: java, fileutils

```
File spf = new File(setspath);
//
List lst =  new List();
lst.add(sourcej);
lst.add(folname);
lst.add(chosenBackup);
//
FileUtils.writeLines(spf, lst);
```

I get this error "The method writeLines(File, Collection) in the type FileUtils is not applicable for the arguments (File, List)" in eclipse

I'm guessing you have to make List into a Collection, but I can't find how to do that anywhere.
Help?

Comment: are you sure that *List lst =  new List();* even compiles? List is an interface, it cannot be instantiated. You should do List lst = new ArrayList(); instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is a subclass of [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) it is not a `class`; it is an `interface`. On your second line, you cannot construct an object of type `List`.

If you use an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead (e.g.: `List lst =  new ArrayList();`, and import `java.util.ArrayList`) what youa re doing should work.